# Run a method instead of yelling AttributeError

Tags: python, object, attributes

Is it possible to create a class that, when instantiated, would never throw  AttributeError, but instead would call own method to *define* the attribute?

Currently, I can do:

```
class O: pass

o = O()

o.car = O()
o.car.type = "family"
o.car.color = "red"

o.car.trail = O()
o.car.trail.color = "yellow"

o.house = O()
o.house.size = "small"
o.house.number = 87
```

I'm trying to create an arbitrary hierarchy out of a set of generic objects.  Only purpose is to hold arbitrary data i.e. no need to define `class Car:` or `class House:`.

Now I wonder if it's possible to define a "magical" method that would be called each time an attribute is not found:

```
class O:
   def __magically_define_attribute__(self, name):
       setattr(self, name, O())
```

so I could omit all the `O()`s and simply do:

```
o = O()

o.car.type = "family"
o.car.color = "red"
o.car.trail.color = "yellow"
o.house.size = "small"
o.house.number = 87
```

So is it possible?  And if not, is there a specific reason for that?

(Yes, it's about data, so I know I should probably use hierarchy of dictionaries here, *but* I still wonder if it's possible since compared to dict syntax, dot syntax is obviously way easier to read and write.)

Comment: `__getattr__` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class Obj(object):
    def __getattr__(self,x):
        setattr(self,x,Obj())
        return getattr(self,x)

o = Obj()
o.car.type = "family"
o.car.color = "red"

print o.car.color
```

Answer (score 1):

the [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattr__#object.__getattr__) method looks like it should fufill your needs.  It is invoked when

> an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places
>   (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class
>   tree for self). name is the attribute name